# Where do I find my "your app ID"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Where do I find my Your app id? and do i change the -dot- to . ? I tried all the numbers and usernamese I have "Log in to phpMyAdmin  Also tried following the steps in the gude.  I'm trying to get to my myphyadmin
"You can now log in to phpMyAdmin. The config.inc.php file that you deployed allowed for logging in without a password. For now, that's how you'll log in, until you set passwords in the next section.      In your web browser, enter the URL for phpMyAdmin to open the welcome page, changing the URL to use your app ID.          https://phpmyadmin-dot-[YOUR_APP_ID].appspot.com"

Comment: What guide are you talking about? What service are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the reply :).   Google server and this one: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine

Comment: As the OP you always have the ability to edit your original question. Please do that (as well) when adding new insights and additional information rather than only posting such details in comments.

Answer (score 2):

The app engine application id is your project id. You can find it with cloud platform console. See [Locate the project ID and project number](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158840?hl=en) from Cloud Platform Console Help